Fedimint for Privacy
I heard from a podcast that a way to enforce privacy in your coins while DCA'ing could be sending your lightning BTC to a fedimint, and then send it to on-chain. What privacy properties would one be able to expect from this procedure vs coinjoin/mixing?

"Is this the new norm?" is probably a matter of opinion or research. Given that we try to focus on facts and expertise here, your question might be a better fit if you were aiming for something more answerable, e.g. "What privacy properties would one be able to expect from this procedure?"

Thanks! I updated the question accordingly
